# Springboot 1.5.1 Upgrade - MVC Exception Handling Issues

Tags: spring-boot

In our application we use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` to handle all kind of `exceptions` and report those as `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` as below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleAllExceptions() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Besides that, we also have handler to take care of `NOT_FOUND` exceptions for the application using `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` bean to return a customised **pageNotFound** template as below:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/404").setViewName("pageNotFound");
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return (container) -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                                                                "/404"));
    }
```

This has been working all fine till SBSP 1.4.X versions but since we migrated our app to SBSP 1.5.1, the `NOT_FOUND` handler is broken and the app now returns the configured customised error page as per `handleAllExceptions` from `@ExceptionHandler` above.

It's unclear if there is a change in behaviour of the `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` configuration since 1.5.1 but the config is not working as before as the @ControllerAdvice looks like taking over all exception handlers blanket-ing the 404 handler in our code.

Any suggestions or guidance would be helpful to know the reason and a fix/workaround.

Thanks in adv!

**----EDIT----**

As suggested by Andy please find below the a sample project that proves the issue/behaviour.

**App Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NotFoundApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotFoundApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/404").setViewName("pageNotFound");
        }

        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
            return (container) -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                    "/404"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = NotFoundApplication.class,
        webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class NotFoundPageIT extends FluentTest {

    private WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Page
    private NotFoundPage notFoundPage;

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultBaseUrl() {
        return "http://localhost:" + port;
    }

    @Test
    public void showPageNotFoundWhenEndPointDoesNotExist() throws Exception {
        goTo("/notFound");
        notFoundPage.isAt();
    }

    public static class NotFoundPage extends FluentPage {

        @Override
        public void isAt() {
            assertThat(title()).contains("404 Page Unavailable");
            assertThat(find("body").getText()).contains("The requested page is not found");
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>404 Page Unavailable</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>The requested page is not found</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Easiest way to verify is by running the test cases present in the code base.

The main test to look for is - `showPageNotFoundWhenEndPointDoesNotExist`, which explains the behaviour under test. The test would pass with run with Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE version **but** fail when the version is upgraded to the latest 1.5.1.RELEASE.

The another imp bit to notice is that, if `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` is removed from the SpringBootApplication annotated class, the test case would pass and the behaviour is as expected. That might further help zero down to potential problematic area to look at.

For our complete usecase we need to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and  hence the issue is inevitable.

Comment: On further investigation, we removed the `@ControllerAdvice` class and the `error.html` template file in order to see if that lets the added ErrorPage come into play but then the White-label Error Page for `404` is displayed instead of the customised page. It indicates that, `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` bean configuration might be the one that is failing to give the desired results.

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) for the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - A complete code is provided in the EDIT section above. Please let me know if it doesn't suffice.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a complete example. For example, I can't run it without guessing what all your dependencies are and what versions you're using. A Git repository that can be cloned and run would be more useful.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - here it is now - https://github.com/ashwgupt/stackoverflow-42384352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8477) in Spring Boot 1.5.1 which means that the `ErrorPageFilter` is registered whenever you subclass `SpringBootServletInitializer`. It should only be registered when you package your application as a war and deploy it to a standalone container. This unwanted filter is breaking your custom error page configuration. The bug will be fixed in 1.5.2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation